# Simple String Replace in Knockout

Tags: javascript, string, knockout.js

I keep getting the following error when trying to do a simple string replace with an observable.

> str.replace is not a function

Here's a sample of what I mean. I got the following observable, which works fine:

```
this.price = ko.observable(data.price);
this.priceFloat = ko.computed(function() {
return parseFloat( Math.abs(viewModel.price()) ).toFixed(2);
}, this);
```

As to why I need a computed version and an observable version of the same number is another issue. Now I need to remove my commas, which is pretty basic. I simply did this in my console and it worked.

```
var str = "3,047";
var nw = str.replace(',', '');
console.log(nw);
```

But when I put it in the computed function, it returns the error.

```
this.price = ko.observable(data.price);
this.priceFloat = ko.computed(function() {
    var str = viewModel.price();
    var nw = str.replace(',', '');
    console.log(nw);
return parseFloat( Math.abs(viewModel.price()) ).toFixed(2);
}, this);
```

I tried the following as well but it didn't work, it still returns the same error.

```
ko.extenders.removeComma = function(target) {

  var result = ko.computed({
    read: function () { return target(); },
    write: function (v) { 
      target(v.replace(/\,/g, ''));
    }
  });
  return result;
};
this.price = ko.observable(data.price).extend({removeComma: ""});
```

Does anyone know why is this so? Any explanation would be appreciated.

Comment: Please log out the `console.log(str);` before calling replace on it, then you will see what `viewModel.price()` returns!

Comment: @Rachelle Uy Can you post the error message you receive?

Comment: @nemesv I know, then after the string replace function it doesn't work. :(

Comment: @FeistyMango It's as simple as _str.replace is not a function_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most likely it's because the observable is returning a value **that isn't a string** which would cause this error. See below for a way to handle that:

```
this.price = ko.observable(data.price);
this.priceFloat = ko.computed(function() {
    var str = viewModel.price() ? viewModel.price().toString() : '';
    var nw = str.replace(',', '');
    console.log(nw);
return parseFloat( Math.abs(viewModel.price()) ).toFixed(2);
}, this);
```

Edit:

http://jsfiddle.net/Qbc7Z/3/

Comment: If `str` would be `undefined` then the error message would be `Cannot call method 'replace' of undefined` and not `str.replace is not a function`...

Comment: @nemesv You are right. In reality it has to be that the value isn't undefined or null but rather, the wrong type. Updated code to match that.

Answer (score 2):

In commented ko you can use like this...

```
<!-- ko text: address().telephone.toString().replace(/(\d{3})(\d{3})(\d{4})/, "($1) $2-$3") --><!-- /ko --><br/>
```